# What time a instance of an object created and assigned in dependency injection

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, structuremap

Suppose we have a controller in MVC,like to this:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
        IProductService _productService;
        ICategoryService _categoryService;
        IUnitOfWork _uow;
        public HomeController(IUnitOfWork uow, IProductService productService, ICategoryService categoryService)
        {
            _productService = productService;
            _categoryService = categoryService;
            _uow = uow;
        }

        // ...
}
```

we use StructureMap for Dependency Injection,and now in Global..asax.cs we have a code like to this:

```
...           
 ObjectFactory.Initialize(x =>
            {
                x.For<IUnitOfWork>().HttpContextScoped().Use(() => new EFCodeFirstContext());
                x.ForRequestedType<ICategoryService>().TheDefaultIsConcreteType<EfCategoryService>();
                x.ForRequestedType<IProductService>().TheDefaultIsConcreteType<EfProductService>();
            });
...
```

### Now my Question is:

for example what time a instance of EfCategoryService be created and assigned to _categoryService?

1- any time we use _categoryService in any method in this controller?

**OR**

2-Immediately when a request to this controller sended? for example,

www.sitename.com/Home

or

www.sitename.com/Home/News

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should let ASP .NET MVC know that you're using StructureMap for dependency injection.

You can do it by providing an `IControllerFactory`

Before wiring the routing (in the begining of your program) use this code-

```
ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(new StractureMapControllerFactory());
```

Where `StructureMapControllerFactory` will provide the implementation to use the DI container when instantiating Controllers

I've never done it with StructureMap but I guess someone has already implemented the ContorllerFactory for StructureMap.

Comment: @user197508 yes, answer is 2. Obviously, one cannot construct an instance of `HomeController` without first having the three dependency instances ready (there's no other way to call the constructor).